# Asserting the type of values in a generic object in typescript

Tags: typescript

Sorry as this seems like something simple but I can't find how to do it.

Let's say I have an array A of some unknown size, and an array B of the same size of say numbers. And I zip them together to create an object W with keys from A paired with numbers from B.

Of course generally I just mean I have an object of some unknown size created from some generated keys and generated values which I know the type of.

How do I declare the type of W (say for the purpose of defining a function)? I would like to say something like object< type > but this doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{[key:string]:any}
```

where `string` is the type of the keys and `any` is the type of the values